# Python stops working while importing Theano

Tags: python, theano

I'm trying to use Theano and when I import it, i get a pop up saying python.exe has stopped working. What's the problem?This is my .theanorc file

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = cuda0
mode=FAST_RUN

[cuda]
root = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin


[nvcc]
fastmath = True

[dnn]

include_path = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include
library_path = C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64
```

Comment: Are you using GPU? Can you post your `.theanorc`?

Comment: Yes i do. I put the contents in the question just now. @Kh40tiK

Comment: Does it only break when using GPU? What if you add `preallocate=0.2` under a new section `[gpuarray]`?

Comment: Still the same thing comes up on the screen. I dint try to use the cpu version, before i configure the .theanorc file, everything was working just fine. The problem arised when i configured the .theanorc file for gpu.

Comment: Try updating to everything to dev version. If the problem persists, go for [theano-users](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/theano-users) mailing list or github issues.

Answer (score 0):

put your code in try except then check the exception please.

try:

....

except Exception as ex:

print("Error: "+str(ex))